# PCL libraries and similar File.Exists functions

Tags: dll, xamarin, portable-class-library

Im new in the new version of Mono 4.2 and they implement the new PCL libraries, My question is there is a similar function like File.Exists that works on PCL, and if I mix this libraries with the full ones, there will be a problem with the compatibility of this dll in iOs.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File System is handled differently on each operation system, so you are going to need to write platform specific code, or use pre-made cross-platform framework's plug-ins.

I suggest you to take a look at [MVVMCross framework](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross), for mobile development in general, and specifically at the [File Plugin of MVVMCross](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use my [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) library for cross-platform file IO access.  It doesn't have a separate method to check for existence of a file, but you can call `IFolder.GetFileAsync` and check if it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.